# How to disable opening new browser tab by Ctrl + click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day.
I have a list of some products. I realized multiple select products using Ctrl key.

```
$(parentSelector).on("click", function (evnt) {
                    evnt.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    var item = $(evnt.delegateTarget)
                    // TODO: clarify how to rewrite event handling
                    if (!evnt.ctrlKey && !evnt.metaKey) {
                        var selectedItems = $("#tabs .popup-body").find("a.item.selected");
                        $.each(selectedItems, function () {
                            $(this).removeClass("selected");
                        });
                    } else {
                        if (item.hasClass("selected")) {
                            item.removeClass("selected")
                        } else {
                            item.addClass("selected")
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

In "else" block product becomes selected or not selected.
But while tab isn't loaded fully, Ctrl+click opens new tab, how to prevent it? 
Thank you.

Comment: You can wrap it within `$(window).load()` method then. it will wait for things to be loaded then register the click event.

Comment: Have you tried with jquery preventDefault ?

Comment: Don't give your `<a>` an href.   Then it can't be clicked.  If you need the href, call it something else on the page render then onload set it back.

Comment: **@all:** It's a terrible idea to interfere with expected behavior. HTML hyperlinks are meant to *redirect* the user to some other content, and how it's done is browser's problem (and users'). **If you provide me a hyperlink which doesn't open in a new tab if I control+click it, I will find a way around that, and get pissed at you.**

Comment: @Nikolai: What *freedomn-m* said. You have a list, and there are standard HTML elements for that. Check [`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li), [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) and [`<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you need something like this?

```
   element.onclick = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      //do stuff
    };
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/okoRorU/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a href="https://example.com" class="disable-ctrl-click">Users cannot open this link in new tab by Ctrl+click</a>
```

JavaScript (vanilla):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName('disable-ctrl-click');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(link) {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

JavaScript (with jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.disable-ctrl-click').click(function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```